# Implementation of javax.servlet

Tags: tomcat

Where can I find the implementation of ServletResponse/HttpServletResponse and ServletRequest/HttpServletRequest in the tomcat source code?

Tried finding implementations in source but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 5):

For `HttpServletRequest` , its implementation is [`org.apache.catalina.connector.Request`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java). Some of its methods may further delegated to [`org.apache.coyote.Request`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/coyote/Request.java) which is the most raw request object used internally.

For `HttpServletResponse`, the Servlet implementation and the most raw response object are [`org.apache.catalina.connector.Response`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.java) and [`org.apache.coyote.Response`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/coyote/Response.java) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Servlet API documentation for Apache Tomcat, reference to which can be easily found on it's official site, for example here is the latest API docs:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

check the following section:

**All Known Implementing Classes**: *HttpServletRequestWrapper*

Now, a simple search through the sources will give you the following location:

**source_root_dir**/java/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.java

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the source class and it contains an HttpServletRequest inside - how does that get populated? The Wrapper class seems to be invoking most of its methods on the underlying request object.